# How to use thumbnail size of image if I'm only using src to get image

Tags: php, custom-field, images, advanced-custom-fields, thumbnails

I have a custom field for an image, and using it this way:

```
<?php $item_img = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $item_img ?>" />
```

But I want to use the thumbnail version of the image, as set to 150x150 in wordpress.

How do I do that with this type of setup?

Do I have to set a custom `add_image_size()` or does wordpress have duplicated thumbmail size images?

Comment: You can't do that this way, unless you use native WordPress functions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `get_sub_field()` i assume you are inside a `have_rows()` (a repeater), in theory it should work like this:

```
$image = get_sub_field('image');
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
```

and this is what you can get:

```
$image['url'] //this is the full image
echo $image['sizes']['medium']; //medium image
echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; //thumbnail image
echo $image['sizes']['yourcustomsize']; //custom sized image
```

another way is to use:

```
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imageID, $size );
```

now if these dont work for you, that means your images are still saved as just the URL, not the object. try re-saving the post/page where the image is uploaded or if you have a set of images, you might need to use another plugin to reupload and create the `sizes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit the field in Custom Fields > Field Groups to return the ID. Then you can use it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_sub_field( 'image' ), 'thumbnail' )[0]; ?>">
```

If it's not in your control, and the field is set to only return the url, you can set the 2nd argument of `get_sub_field()` to `false` to get the ID, since ACF always saves the ID regardless of that setting, and setting that to `false` means that you get the raw value.

So that would be:

```
<?php $image_id = get_sub_field( 'image', false ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' )[0]; ?>">
```